# jQuery not applying class to list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, class

[This is my page.](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_cast-iron-guide-sizes_10151_-1_20002)

It was developed by a 3rd party and I plugged it into our CMS.  Anytime I try to update the page in any way - even something as simple as changing a URL, the list items in the modals when you click the plus sign stop populating.

What is supposed to happen is that each modal window has little icons that appear over the (currently empty) orange bar, and when you hover over the icon, the content below changes.  It looks like this[image], and the code looks like this:

```
            <ul class="size_banner">                                
            <li><a class="size_1 selected" title=""></a></li> 
            <li><a class="size_2" title=""></a></li> 
            <li><a class="size_3" title=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="size_4" title=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="size_5" title=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="size_6" title=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="size_7" title=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="size_8" title=""></a></li>
            </ul>
```

At one point, I figured out that if I edited the page in a text-editor, rather than directly in the CMS and then copied the new code, it would work. However, once again it isn't working! There are no errors in Firebug console or Chrome. [I put the jQuery in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDsDe/), though I get an error when I try to trigger the modal.

[Here is a working version of the page on a different server](http://lizlantz.com/site/cast-iron-guide-sizes.html).

I have to have the page fixed by tomorrow AM so the broken page will only be live today.

Comment: sorry, but where is you jQuery code?

Comment: Can u check if your getting any error on Firebug console?

Comment: Can you post a previously working version ? otherwise there is nothing to compare to .. Most likely your CMS is modifying some parts of the page (*like removing a script or some classes*) on which the rest of the functionality depends.. perhaps it gets wrapped in a `p` and the script does not account for that..

Comment: (*also your page would benefit a lot by some whitespace removal and html minification.. around 50% in size*)

Comment: so i just checked the link you provided. and your anchor tags in the list items are replaced by secure whitespaces

Comment: Sorry, thought you could see the jQuery via view source. I have added it in a fiddle, which of course doesn't work either. Unfortunaely I can't publish content to the site on the fly so I can't post a working version of the page at this point.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, completely agree on the whitespace, unfortunately it's beyond my control.

Comment: @dreamweiver, no errors in any browser, makes it so hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli i guess there is no "previously working version". someone just plugged in some page from a third party to their official appearance and forgot the testing..

Comment: @Vogel612 Just got a working version of the page up.  Your comment about forgetting testing...not very nice. But I do appreciate your attention to my issue and trying to help.

Comment: working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/VDsDe/1/ (*removed the second jquery version*)

Comment: @surfbird0713 ususally i am not that mean, but seriously. how can you overlook something so grave, when setting official sites productive. also Gaby was so nice to post a working jsFiddle, the only thing left is diffchecking and looking for the "why?". please accept my apologies. in my company we usually do 3 days of testing before setting a single site LIVE to the intranet (where noone except our guys sees it), that's why i am kinda surprised on how this could happen ...

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - sorry, I was sloppy with that fiddle and left the 2nd jQuery reference the site that I tested to see if that would work.  The site I'm plugging this into already has the 1.3.2 referenced, and I do see that it is being called twice on the current page that is live. However, if I remove the second reference the page still doesn't work in the staging environment, so I don't think removing the second reference will fix it.

Comment: @Vogel612, apology accepted, thank you. I am a team of one, and being only human, things get missed sometimes. I would be thrilled to have help with my QA and testing, and it is rare that anything ever goes to production broken. This one slipped through as it was one of 56 pages I updated in one day. 3 days of testing sounds heavenly.

Comment: @surfbird0713 i figured so about the 2 jquery versions.. just posted for the working fiddle for others to play (*hadn't seen you added a different url in your original post*) - added an answer with my findings.. (*blame the CMS for removing empty elements..*)

Comment: well it is the intranet after all (well it used to be) and if you have such a (sorry) sh*tload of work in one day, then it is not really surprising the one or other thing slips through. i guess you can't just go to you CO and hit him in the face for not having you helped by some people (testing is not that difficult ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after comparing the working version with the non-working version the result is that the CMS has altered the actual html that is being rendered..

It has nothing to do with the scripts..

See http://www.diffnow.com/?report=vknwc

On the left is the non-working code and on the right the working code (*for just the first size*).

You will notice that on the working version (*the right*) each `li` element has an empty `a` tag inside it with some attributes.

Your CMS obviously considers those elements as useless because they are empty and removes them.

You will need to re-add them (*and perhaps give them a `&nbsp` inside so they are not treated as empty*)

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!! It's fixed! Thank you so much. I added &nbsp; and it is working across browsers.  Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption,

```
<ul class="size_banner">
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
  <li> </li>
</ul>
```

As far as i know, these  **"li"** where tags where suppose to have those small images appearing within the modal, so can u check the jquery`s modal plugin code, whether the images src were configured properly or not.

Happy Coding :)